# HLSL: packing error?

Tags: c++, graphics, hlsl

I am passing in a constant buffer with the following layout:

```
struct 
{
    float spread;
    D2D1_POINT_2F dimension;
    D2D1_POINT_2F dimension2;
} m_constants;
```

for debugging sake, dimension and dimension2 have the same values.

In the shader i have:

```
cbuffer constants
{
    float spread;
    float2 dimension;
    float2 dimension2;
};

float4 main(
    float4 pos      : SV_POSITION,
    float4 posScene : SCENE_POSITION,
    float4 uv0      : TEXCOORD0
    ) : SV_Target
{
    float width = dimension.x;
    float height = dimension.y;
    float2 uv2 = float2(posScene.x / width, posScene.y / height);
    color.rgb = float3(uv2.xy,  0);
    return color;
}
```

this, in theory, should output a gradient with green on the bottom left and red at the top right. And it does.
But if, in the shader i have the width and height to use dimension2 instead. i get a horizontal gradient from green on the left to yellow on the right.

Why is that? both dimensions have the same value when i passed the m_constants to the shader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constant buffers data is aligned by 16 bytes by default, so this means:

```
cbuffer constants
{
    float spread;
    float2 dimension;
    float2 dimension2;
};
```

will be

```
cbuffer constants
{
    float spread; // 4 bytes
    float2 dimension; // 4 + 8 = 12 bytes
    float dummy; //12+8 = 20, which means we cross 16 for dimension 2, hence a dummy 4 bytes element is added
    float2 dimension2;
};
```

here is a [link](http://blog.signalsondisplay.com/?p=244) that describes this.

So a better way to arrange your structure would be:

```
struct 
{
    D2D1_POINT_2F dimension;
    D2D1_POINT_2F dimension2;
    float spread;
} m_constants;
```

and modify the hlsl counterpart accordingly:

```
cbuffer constants
{
    float2 dimension;
    float2 dimension2;
    float spread; // No more 16 bytes crossing problem
};
```

Another way, without modifying initial layout, in c++ side, either declare your structure like:

```
#pragma pack(push)
#pragma pack(16) 
struct 
{
    float spread;
    D2D1_POINT_2F dimension;
    D2D1_POINT_2F dimension2;     
} m_constants;
#pragma pack(pop)
```

That will force structure to be 16 bytes aligned.

You can also use /Zp16 compiler flag , but that will then apply to every structure in your program (which is not always desirable). In visual studio go to project properties -> c/c++ -> Code Generation, then you have option "Struct Member Alignment", where you can set it from.

You can also use packoffset on hlsl side, but then it means that the c++ layout needs to match the packed hlsl one (which means you keep same order in hlsl constant buffer, but still have to modify the c++ version).

Comment: yep that solved it! just out of curiosity, is there a way to preserve the first layout but somehow use packoffset to solve the problem?

Comment: also, why did the first layout not work in the first place? you would expect the compile to pack spread and dimension into a chunk and dimension2 into another...

Comment: Just modified answer (since i think it fits better in there), to explain how to do it with the layout preserving.